# methods to calculate the difference in time and distance

Tags: java

I am creating a public transportation card. I would like your help in defining three related methods:

```
isCheckedIn(long time)
```

return whether it was succesfully checked in within the last 120 minutes, and has not been checked out since the last succesful checkIn.

```
checkIn(int x, int y, long time)
```

Which

- x and y are parameters, which is the current location
- If checking in a new journey, message: "Checked In".
- If continuing the current one if already checked in, message: "Continued journey".
- Can keep travelling forever, as long as you check in at least every 120 minutes.

checkOut(int x, int y, long time)

Which:

- Ends the current journey and deducts the price for the whole journey from the balance, using the formula 12 + (maxX - minX + maxY - minY) * 3, where the max and min are taken over all coordinates of checkIns and the final checkOut.

Example messages:

- "Checked out! Price is $2, remaining balance is $98"
- "Error: Cannot check out; Not currently checked in"

What I have done so far:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class TravelCard {

//Card balance
private int balance;

// isCheckedIn
private boolean isCheckedIn;
private Instant instant;

// distant x,y
private int x;
private int y;



public TravelCard()

{
    balance = 100;
    isCheckedIn = false;


}

public void depositMoney(int amount) {


    if (amount >= 0) {
        balance += amount;
        System.out.println(amount + " dollars deposited. New balance: " + balance + " dollars");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot deposit negative amount");
    }

}

public boolean isCheckedIn(long time) {

    Instant instant1 = Instant.now();
    time = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(instant, instant1);

    // time
    if (isCheckedIn && time <= 120) return true;
    else return false;

}

public void checkIn(int x, int y, long time) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    if (time == 0) {
        System.out.println("Checked in");
    } else if (time <= 120) {
        System.out.println("Continued journey");
    }

}


public void checkOut(int x, int y, long time) {

}



public static void main(String[] args) {


     }

}
```

I completely got lost in checkOut method, except the method to print the messages. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

The code written below is just to show you a way that how can you store the maximum and minimum values for x and y. Other way to do this is to store all x and y values in array. But the memory consumption will increase unnecessarily.

```
public TravelCard(){
    x_min = 9999999;
    y_min = 9999999;
    x_max = 0;
    y_max = 0;
    balance = 100;
    isCheckedIn = false;
}

public void checkIn(int x, int y, long time) {
    //we save the new x and y, only if they are larger than previous ones
    if (x >this.x_max){
        this.x_max = x;
    } else if(x < this.x_min){
        this.x_min = x;
    }
    if (y >this.y_max){
        this.y_max = y;
    } else (y<y_min){
        this.y_min = y;
    }


    if (ischeckedIn()) {
        System.out.println("Continued Journey");
    } else if {
        System.out.println("CheckingIn Now");
        this.instant = Instant.now()
        isCheckedIn = true;
    }

 }

public boolean isCheckedIn(l) {

    Instant instant1 = Instant.now();
    if(this.isCheckedIn){
        time = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(instant, instant1);
    } else {
         return false;
    }

    // time
    if (isCheckedIn && time <= 120) return true;
    else{
        System.out.println("Your time is out! i.e Auto Checkout")
        this.isCheckedIn = false;
        return false;
}
public void checkOut(int x,int y,long time){
    if(this.isCheckedIn){
        //updating x and y at checkout time
        if (x >this.x_max){
            this.x_max = x;
        } else if(x < this.x_min){
            this.x_min = x;
        }
        if (y >this.y_max){
            this.y_max = y;
        } else (y<y_min){
            this.y_min = y;
        }
        //Now we alredy have max and min for x and y
        int expense = 12 +((this.x_max - this.x_min)+(this.y_max - this.y_min))*3;
        this.balance = this.balance - expense;
        System.out.println("Expense for trip: "+expense+", Available Balance:" +this.balance);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot check out; Not currently checked in");
}
```

Even after writing this code, there still persist a problem, if person is auto checked out after 120 mins, how will you retrieve the x and y value at that exact 120th min. In real life we constantly listen to change in x and y values in, and update it continuously.

Comment: I see that this thread has been placed on hold, but I would just mention for OP that this solution might cause a problem on starting a journey. The checkIn function should set the min and max coordinates to the passed in x and y when a journey has just started in order to appropriately track min/max

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a college homework problem. I think it would likely be more helpful to have the full context of the question rather than just your interpretation of it. For example, why does the isCheckedIn() function require you to pass it a time value? Is that a requirement or is it just your interpretation of how the answer should be. You don't actually seem to be using the variable for any calculations, so the result wouldn't change whether I put it 0 or 1000. I would also suggest asking your TA/teacher for help before coming here since it's such a specific problem and you'd likely get more immediate help.

However, to try to answer some of your questions.

```
ischeckedIn(lomg time)
```

The first thing I notice is that you use the instant variable without having initialized it in the constructor. It looks like that variable shouldn't have a value until checkIn time, so you should have a null check around that logic. The second thing is that since you have a value to see if the ticket was previously checked in, that should be your first step so you're not repeating work:

```
public boolean isCheckedIn() {
    if(!isCheckedIn) return false;
    ....
    //some logic
}
```

The second thing about the function is that since 120 is a constant for your checked in time, you should really move it out of the function and store it as a static final int for your class.

I would also suggest that if your isCheckedIn() method is going to return false, then you should set the isCheckedIn value to false until they check in again.

```
checkIn(int x, int y, long time)
```

There are a number of points here. Since you need to track the minimum and maximum of x and y, you need either to store you checkin coordinates in some kind of array, or you need to have 3 variables for the coordinates. minX, maxX, currentX and the same for y.

After doing the logic to store your coordinates, you should check if the person is already checked in.

```
if(isCheckedIn(time)) {
    // your logic
}
```

Your current method will fail if the time is >120 minutes. It might be better to have some method here that fails the checkIn process if time is >120 with a message saying they must pay their balance before checking in again. If you are checked in, your time value should be used to create a new instant to replace your old one. I would consider making your return values a string so you can let the consumer of your method decide what to do with the result.

```
checkOut(int x, int y, long time)
```

This method should be pretty similar to the checkIn method. Your first step should be to check if you are actually checked in.

```
if(!isCheckedIn(time)) {
    // return error message
}
```

If you are checked in, then you do the same logic you made for checkIn to store the coordinates. At that point, you can just run your formula for calculating cost, decrement your balance, and return your message.